# Per mangiare/per mangio, ma non ingrasso

Tags: prepositions

I'm wondering what the meaning/function of 'per' is in the above sentence.

What would the difference be between:

Per mangio, ma non ingrasso
Vs.
Mangio, ma non ingrasso

Comment: The sentence "Mangio, ma non ingrasso" means "I eat, but I don't put on weight". It doesn't make sense adding a preposition at the beginning of this sentence. That is, the sentence "Per mangio, ma non ingrasso" means nothing, it would be something like "For I eat, but I don't put on weight".

Answer (score 6):

*Per mangio, ma non ingrasso* is not an Italian sentence.

*Mangio, ma non ingrasso* is correct, and means “I eat [and it is probably implied that I eat whenever and whatever I want], but I don't grow fat”.

Perhaps you had in mind something like *Per mangiare mangio, ma non ingrasso*, which would simply mean “As to eating, I do eat, but I don't grow fat”.

Comment: As said by @DaG, the sentence "Per mangiare, mangio, ma non ingrasso" do make completely sense in Italian. Saying "Per mangiare, mangio" instead of simply "Mangio" you are putting more emphasis on the fact that you are eating.